# How to .animate() a background-image size

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I .animate a background-image size with javascript/jquery?

The code where wt_r and ht_r are the screen size.  Can I make that dynamic with .animate()?

```
$('#outer').css('background-size',wt_r+' '+ht_r);
```

jsfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/m7zmzkpz/1/

Comment: Can you explain what's the initial background image size? Why use animate() instead of simply setting the bg image to `100%` in CSS? Have you tried using CSS3's `transition`? What means dynamic? What you want to achieve? Also if `wt_r` returns i.e: `1200` you're missing the `unit`!

Comment: You could create an interceptor of `$.fn.animate()`, and use CSS tranistions for background-size. Still don't get why it **has** to be solved with `.animate()`, though.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan to dynamically increase the background image size as the browser window is size is changed.setting 100% in css is not something I am looking for.

Comment: @d_inevitable I did not understand what you wrote

Comment: @X10nD what means *dynamically*? there's nothing dynamical in what you're doing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan when i resize the browser window the background image should resize

Comment: @X10nD what's wrong with this? http://jsbin.com/varecu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i resize the browser window the background image should resize –  X10nD 3 mins ago

**No JS needed at all...**

```
  background-size:100% 100%; // or just 100% to keep Aspect-Ratio
```

http://jsbin.com/varecu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

- Animate on page load? No JS needed at all:

http://jsbin.com/xuhuca/1/edit?html,css,js,output

- Want to keep aspect ratio but fill all the spaces? `background-size: cover;`

http://jsbin.com/varecu/2/edit

<sub>(Resize the window on all those demos to see the magic. The background-image resizes!)</sub>

Comment: I tried to put in this pic - http://wallpoper.com/images/00/44/95/50/autumn-scenery-2_00449550.jpg and the image does not resize with window resize

Comment: @X10nD I don't understand your comment, I've provided you with 3 jsBin links where you can simply change the image url to see the result: http://jsbin.com/varecu/4/ and http://jsbin.com/varecu/3/ >> resize or EDIT the jsBins at will.

Comment: Sorry @roko now its coming correctly.. Thank you so much.  let me check on.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change both height and width of a background-image.

Using .animate():

```
$('#outer').animate({backgroundSize: '100%'}, 800);
```

Comment: Not the downvote, but `100%` should be a string. And IMO setting a var for the duration in this example complecates things more than it helps

Comment: edited, forgot :D (it complicates things but op didn't know what the parameter was used for)

Comment: This is the correct answer. [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/xnmpmahh/)  If the checkbox is ticked, resize tries to use 'animate', setting width+height - it doesn't work. If it's unticked, it calls the resize stuff without animate - and it works.

Comment: @Ax_6 that 100% you have there is for width or height?

Comment: That will change the width of the image. Height will adapt based on the  image proportions

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to answer question without more information, but you can try animate your background size with backgroundSize property? like this:

```
$('#outer').animate({ backgroundSize: '100%' }, 3000);
```

Try to use your own parameters wt_r and ht_r as backgroundSize value

Hope this helps!

Comment: 3000 is 3000ms - time take to do animation - try to play with that value in order to achieve perfect time for animation. This code is just for image size - not image position

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes its the ms value, it quite slipped out of my mind. thanks

Comment: I did '$('#outer').animate({ backgroundSize: wt_r+' '+ht_r }, 3000);'  It does not seem to work still..  The image is over 3000px.

Comment: Can you provide us with the link, jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @Matas see Ax's answer.

Comment: @X10nD You forgot to include jQuery in the fiddle. But as Ax_6 said, you can't use both height and width of a background image, use percentage instead to keep aspect ratio. Not 100% sure what is your use case and what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want #outer to fit the screen size you could do soemthing like this:

```
var setSize = function(w, h) {
   $('#outer').css({
      'background-size': w + 'px ' + h + 'px'
   })
}
```

The setSize function takes two parameters, width and height. You can call this function from wherever you need it, f.ex on resize. You can pass the current window width and height into the function like this:

```
window.on(resize, function(){

   var wt_r = $(window).width();
   var ht_r = $(window).height();

   setSize(wt_r, ht_r);

})
```

Comment: You did not tested this, did you?